# Some Mesh won't follow the rig and weight painting and rig is lagging

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, rigify

I'm new to blender and i'm making a human 3D model and somehow some part of my mesh won't follow the rig,first i modeled each of the meshes separately and then join all of them into 1 mesh and then parent it to meta rig,but somehow only the body,handband and boots follow the rig,hair and dress didn't.

then i was trying to weight coloured the dress and hair but to no avail,not to mention it's very laggy.does someone have any solutions?[my blend file is as follows](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ICkGAv0gOcmoSXi6-QnYSDIC5IUpdfql/view?usp=sharing)

[image: here's my hair and dress didn't follows the rig]

Comment: Without looking at the blend file, I immediately suspect that either the weights are wrong for the dress (and from the screenshot, probably everything else as well). If they truly are all one mash, and there’s no physics on the dress, unless the skeleton is very strange indeed, it pretty much has to be weighting. Lag with deforms is typically because of a ton of vertices in the mesh. Try decimate, limited dissolve, or un-subdivide.

Comment: well,i used automatic weight for the entire mesh.and yes there's no physics on the dress.but how do i apply the physics on the dresses when they are already join in one mesh?should i separate them first?

Comment: No, you don’t want physics. I suspected that there were some physics active.